# How to play mp3 after page load?

Tags: html, github

After creating my demo github pages.
I put following code into the index.html file :

```
 <html>
    <head>
       <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
       <title>My TITLE</title>
       <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="images/icon.ico">
    </head>
    
    <body>
       
       <iframe src="2-seconds-silence.mp3" allow="autoplay" id="audio" style="display: none" hidden=""></iframe>
       <audio id="player" autoplay loop>
          <source src="hello.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
       </audio>
    </body>
 </html>
```

However after loading the page by chrome, it didn't run.
Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Please keep in mind that some browsers/OSes do not even load or play without a user interaction on that page first, by design. This is especially true on older iOS devices.

Comment: And, regarding your file name, why would you want to play silence? Should this test some capability, or try to keep the screen on? There would be other ways to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

You can try it like that. Attribute list: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_audio.asp

```html
<html>
    <head>
       <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
       <title>My TITLE</title>
       <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="images/icon.ico">
    </head>
    
    <body>
       
       <iframe src="2-seconds-silence.mp3" allow="autoplay" id="audio" style="display: none" hidden=""></iframe>

      <script type="text/javascript">
         document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
            var audioTag = document.createElement("AUDIO");

            audioTag.setAttribute("src","hello.mp3");

            document.body.appendChild(audioTag);
         }, false);
      </script>
    </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this:

```
<audio src="mysong.mp3" id="my_audio" loop="loop"></audio>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload=function(){
  document.getElementById("my_audio").play();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First grab the audio element using Javascript.
for eg : `const audio = document.queryselector("#audioId")`
then apply funtion `window.addEventListener("load",() => {audio.play()})`

Answer (score 0):

correct autoplay attribute. Instead of 'autoplay=" "' just leave 'autoplay', same for 'loop'.

Cheers